# Move the storage directory outside of the web directory

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

In opencart version 3 there is a notification:

> It is very imporant that you move the storage directory outside of the
>   web directory (e.g. public_html, www or htdocs)

Screenshot
[image: Screenshot]

I tried by clicking on move button in the picture also tried manually but after trying it is giving weird errors.

Comment: what errors did you see?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can move storage directory outside of the web directory (e.g. public_html, www or htdocs) in three ways

1. Automatically Moving
2. Manual Moving (from admin panel)
3. Manual Moving ( By editing Config files)...

Assuming that you know first and second methods.Here I will explain the third method to you.

1. Copy your storage directory from system/storage to public_html, www or htdocs.
2. Change the following file path from both config files i.e. config.php and admin/config.php as shown below.

   define('DIR_STORAGE', '**public_html**/storage');

Please replace public_html to your desired path.

I hope this answer might help you.

Answer (score 7):

It is very simple to remove / hide this dialog box:

open '**admin/controller/common/dashboard.php**' file

search below line

**$data['security'] = $this->load->controller('common/security');**

and replace it with below line

**$data['security'] = '';**

That's it :)

Comment: removing or hiding the provided code can lead to being security issues. as it is an important thing to move the storage directory outside the root. removing security warning is not good instead solving it.

Comment: Plugin may also help you to remove this dialog box automatically without doing any programming. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change directory path as decribed abowe--but when You save the config.php use utf8 encoding. I have worked 2 hour on it- did everithing i found on google, but nothing worked. Just this simple thing!

Comment: Also add the steps if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this little problem, and the fault was layer 8 (problems between the keyboard and the chair)

I hadn't read the code that I had to change correctly and I was doing it wrong, I'll explain better in case someone runs into the same problem:

[capturing the variable to be deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQhsD.png)

I was just replacing the new directory path, not removing the DIR_SYSTEM variable.

you have to delete DIR_SYSTEM and place the new route. that's all.

For this reason it gave me an error and so I came to this post.

It is my first contribution. I hope this helps you.